# How/When to release resources and resource views in DirectX

Tags: c++, resources, directx

I'm doing working on a DirectX 11 demo application and stumbled over the following problem:
When I create a shader resource view (let's say for a texture) from a file, I have to release it after usage just as every other D3D11 object. But what about the underlying resource, that is created implicitly?

There are three scenarios I can imagine:
+ I should leave the resource alone. It is released by the call to `someShaderResourceView->Release()`
+ I should release it manually together with the shader resource view object.
+ I should release it immediately. This seems to work, although it doesn't seem reasonable to me.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Edit: I'm using the DirectXTex texture loading library, but I would like to keep the question general.

```
ID3D11Resource *resource;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *resourceView;
HRESULT result = CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, path.c_str(), &resource, &texture, 0);
//resource->Release(); ???
```

Instead of `CreateWICTextureFromFile(...)` one could also use the old D3DX11 function `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(...)`.

Comment: Show us your code and what does the documentation say?

Comment: The documentation is pretty unclear, I couldn't find any information on this specific question. It describes only what resources and resource views are and how they are linked in theory, but I couldn't find out what that actually means in this situation.

Comment: You mention using [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki). Keep in mind that the library there is intended more for tools, so it's probably over-kill for your demo. The simpler loaders in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) might be more appropriate although either works. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/) for the reason why there are two different libraries that do the same thing.

Comment: Actually, you are using the WICTextureLoader module if you are using ``CreateWICTextureFromFile``. It's just a standalone version in the DirectXTex package rather than the one that's included with the _DirectX Tool Kit_. The DirectXTex library itself has ``CreateTexture`` and ``CreateShaderResourceView`` which you are not using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct3D uses reference counting (via the `AddRef` and `Release`) methods to control object lifetime, with a few specific quirks because it does not follow all the rules of the general Component Object Model ([COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/the-component-object-model)).

Specifically, if the *only* reference to an object is if you use set it on the device context (a.k.a. bind it to the rendering pipeline), that's not enough to keep it alive because those methods don't increment/decrement the reference count. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-api-features-reference-counting). Therefore your program needs to keep some other reference to the Direct3D objects it is currently using.

The other difference is if the `ID3D11Device` is destroyed because it's reference count hits zero, then it doesn't matter what the reference counts are for all it's `ID3D11DeviceChild` objects and those are all invalid at that point.

You should also keep in mind that Direct3D objects are not actually destroyed until some future point (a.k.a. it uses lazy-destruction) so even if the reference count is zero, it might take a few frames before it's cleaned up fully. This mostly matters if you are dealing with a lot of active resources and have to worry about over-committing--as an aside, you can force pending destructions to complete by using `ID3D11DeviceContext::Flush`, but it's not a good practice for performance to do it often.

**TL;DR:** The `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` object added a reference count to the referenced `ID3D11Resource` object, so as long as the SRV is active the resource is kept alive as well. You only need to take one of the return objects of `CreateWICTextureFromFile`, but you can take both if you want. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) page for the WICTextureLoader module for more information.

> This is a good reason to learn to use the [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer. It takes care of the reference counts if you use it correctly so you can avoid worrying about it in most cases.

**UPDATE:** The topic [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com) from the legacy DirectX SDK is now updated and published on Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thanks! That was exacltly the information I have been looking for.

Comment: I realized last night that the "Introduction to COM for DirectX Programming" documentation topic has disappeared from the web. It was in the DirectX SDK documentation CTM, so it got dropped since we haven't shipped it in 9+ years. I'll make sure to get that on a doc backlog...

Comment: Good answer except ComPtr smart pointers. Old ones, `CComPtr` from ATL, are better: work on all versions of Windows and all compilers, also they have operator `I*` so you don't have to type `Get` every time you pass them to a method.

Comment: BTW, the linked page is deprecated: ATL is now available in all editions of VS including the freeware community edition. MFC too.

Comment: Yes it is available, but it's also an optional component you have to explicitly select in VS 2017's installer.

Comment: Note that the reason ComPtr smart-pointer from WRL does not have the ``operator*`` overload is by design per [this article](https://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/). ATL's CComPtr is basically version 1 of the same smart-pointer, WRL's ComPtr is version 2.